# dnn megamenu posibilities?

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke, megamenu

I haven't worked with dnn very much and for those who also haven't it's basically another CMS tool. I'm working on a mega menu but I am being told that I can't do something because dnn doesn't allow it. I coded a menu idea by myself (html, css, etc.) but have been told this isn't possible or it's never been done so we're not doing it. While I don't have a website example for this kind of menu being used, I know somewhere out there this menu have been used before. My question is have you ever seen this kind of menu used and is dnn really that limiting?
[image: The idea is that when you hover over an item on the left the information on the right changes]

(The idea is that when you hover over an item on the left the information on the right changes)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a highly customized [DDR menu template](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-user-guide).

But a good third-party theme to look at which has a custom menu implementation for DNN is [Mandeep's Porto skin](http://porto.mandeeps.com/).  Click on the link to the demonstration site and hover over the Features menu item.  This is very similar to you want.

You can get tutorials on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DBEFGHxNO0A) and on Mandeep's website.